# I'm trying to export a runnable jar in Eclipse, but I need it to include some other files necessary for running my program

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Specifically, I am using JDBC libraries to work with databases in my Java program. When I perform "Export Runnable Jar" in Eclipse, it includes the referenced libraries but I am never given an option to include my assets folder (containing the databases) in the runnable jar file. If I try to export a regular jar file via Eclipse, I can add the assets folder, but the referenced libraries are not included.

What should I do here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your asset directories declared as Source Folders in Eclipse?

Right Click on the folder, choose Build Path->Use as Source Folder. Then retry the export.

In the longer term, you should really be looking at a build tool such as maven or ant, they are much more flexible, and they are less dependent on Eclipse, so changes in your project configuration in Eclipse won't affect the final build so much.

Comment: This works, but I can only run the program within my main project directory, as it looks for a folder labeled /assets. I think that is on my code side though, thanks a lot! EDIT: Yea my code has this line: `mConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:assets/database1.db");` which I believe means the project looks for a folder called assets/ then inside that looks for the db. I need to change this so it is looking in a source folder.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Ant scripts or maven script to do this.
Where you can import all the referenced jar and files to your desired location.

Personally i liked ant script, since it was easier and you will surely get lot of results for the same if you google.

Comment: Reading up on this now. I'll get back to you with results, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time since I last generated a JAR file with Eclipse, and back in the day I remember the [Fat-Jar Eclipse Plug-in](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) to be quite useful.

Comment: seems like Fat-Jar is the same as Runnable Jar File export option in eclipse. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Oh. What a pity. Too much time without clicking on that option in Eclipse.